# How to filter out warning messages from yum?

Tags: rhel, yum, error-handling

I have installed via `yum` some packages as follows:

```
$ yum install ambari-agent
```

During installation there are a lot of warnings (see below). Is it possible to block these warnings but see only the errors if one occurs?

Expected output should be an ordinary `yum` installation but without warning.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ambari-agent.x86_64 0:2.5.0.3-7 will be updated
---> Package ambari-agent.x86_64 0:2.6.1.0-143 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package            Arch         Version             Repository            Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 ambari-agent       x86_64       2.6.1.0-143         ambari-2.6.1.0        90 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package

Total download size: 90 M
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for ambari-2.6.1.0
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : ambari-agent-2.6.1.0-143.x86_64                              1/2
Upgrading configs in /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini
Values will be updated from /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini.old except the following list: [('heartbeat', 'dirs'), ('heartbeat', 'state_interval')], ['stack', 'puppet', 'command', 'python']
  Cleanup    : ambari-agent-2.5.0.3-7.x86_64                                2/2
warning: file /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.5/services/FALCON/configuration/oozie-site.xml: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/FALCON/configuration/oozie-site.xml: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.1/services/SMARTSENSE/package/files/view/smartsense-ambari-view-1.4.0.2.5.0.3-7.jar: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.1/services/FALCON/configuration/oozie-site.xml: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.1/services/FALCON/configuration: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZEPPELIN/0.6.0.2.5/quicklinks/quicklinks.json: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZEPPELIN/0.6.0.2.5/quicklinks: remove failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Then the package should be fixed.

Comment: we install formal packages from hortonworks , we not manage this at all

Comment: So then tell them to fix their package.

Comment: com-on Be serious ... for now this is the fact , so what we can do regarding that ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `--debuglevel` and/or `--errorlevel` options? See `man yum`

Comment: no , but could you please suggest the syntax that ignore the worming ?

Comment: According the warnings it looks like there were an other Ambari version installed before, and the installation process tries to clean up former ones. Was that a clean installation? Or would an `yum update <package>` be possible? Furthermore I haven't found a way to suppress `yum` warning messages.